# Insert row with increasing numerical ID (e.g. rownum) using Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to insert new rows using Oracle SQL into a table, where one field simply needs to be unique, e.g. simply the rownum value. However this statement does not work:

```
insert into MYTABLE ( ID_, INDEX_, TYPE_, SOMEVALUE_  ) values ( "FOOBAR", rownum, 1, 999 );
```

This will result in an error message:

```
00976. 00000 -  "Specified pseudocolumn or operator not allowed here."
*Cause:    LEVEL, PRIOR, ROWNUM, CONNECT_BY_ROOT, CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF or
           CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE was specified at an illegal location.
```

I am open for an efficient alternate solution, if using rownum is not possible.

Comment: use a sequence as in insert into mytable(...)Values('Foobar', your_sequence.nextval,....)

Comment: `rownum` is **only** available when running a `select` statement. It is not stored anywhere. As kevinsky said: use a sequence if you want a unique number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need here is to create a `SEQUENCE`.

Follow the `SEQUENCE` creation and usage document [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm).

For instance you can create `SEQUENCE` like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mytable_sq
 START WITH     1
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;
```

Then you can do this:

```
insert into MYTABLE ( ID_, INDEX_, TYPE_, SOMEVALUE_  ) values ( "FOOBAR", mytable_sq.nextval, 1, 999 );
```